# How do you fit a 6.8mm Hard Disk in a Caddy that takes a 9.5mm Hard Disk (internal laptop)?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have a *Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA* that is 9.5mm and this slots perfectly with the Motherboard laptop SATA connectors. However the new hard disk 2.5" is 6.8mm high, so how do i get this to fit with the same slot/caddy/motherboard?

Comment: When replacing laptop HDDs with SSDs, I used to stuff the gaps with candy wrappers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time *it just works*.

You don't necessarily need a spacer with a caddy. The 7mm drives have the same screwholes, and the connector's at the position. Simply install the thinner drive exactly the same way as the old drive and it'll fit. I've installed those drives on older thinkpads as upgrades and they work great.

If it slots into the motherboard, topside facing up and the connector on the motherboard, it'll work too. Not too sure if I've seen that arrangement.

I suspect a spacer would be needed if you had a weird design where the drive simply slotted in next to the motherboard, and the connector position relied on the distance between the top of the drive and connector to fit, rather than the standard mounting holes, or if the drive needed to be installed 'upside down' for some reason.

*Typically* this should not be an issue, and I wouldn't buy a spacer until I was sure I needed it.

Comment: On some laptops the hard drives fit in the space in the machine with a snug friction fit and don't use screws at all. I've seen this mainly on older machines but they are out there. I could only find a couple of spacers and a lot of confused "You need what?!" comments so I assume they are less common than my experiences would suggest.

Comment: @Mokubai - Dell is notorious for stuff like that.  Most often it wasn't for notorious reasons just so they could have multiple sources.  Although I am speaking more of a HDD caddy then anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this drive will actually fit fine and connect, but what you are wanting is some kind of spacer to properly align the drive and stop it moving around.

I've found a spacer on [scan.co.uk](http://www.scan.co.uk/products/scanfx-ssd-spacer-for-7mm-to-95mm) that looks promising but as the only description is "SSD spacer to increase height from 7mm to 9.5mm" I don't know if it has adhesive to hold it to the drive or if it is plastic or foam.

[Here](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSD95MMSPFL/) is another spacer.

It appears that [some drives](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Crucial-2-5-inch-Includes-9-5-mm-Spacer/dp/B00KFAGCWK) actually come with spacers, but that's not as helpful *after* you've already bought a drive.

Comment: thanks - that was helpful but what happened was that I took Journeyman's advise and attached the new disk (7mm) the same i would have a 9.5mm (old disk) and with some wiggling it fit and worked. I have a Dell but spacers weren't really necessary because the SATA ports were identically laid out.